# jdbc auto commit features inside a JPA transaction

Tags: java, jdbc, transactional

I have tow method as following:

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public boolean creditAccount(String accountId)
{
      LogUtility.logTxn(accountId);
      // Do somethings 
}

public class LogUtility
{
    javax.sql.DataSource dataSource; // this property initialized in static block of intilalizing LogUtility class

    public logTxn(String account)
    {
       java.sql.Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
       conn.setAutoCommit(true);
       CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(/*name of a oracle package and its procedures*/);
       cStmt.execute();   
    }
}
```

I want understand when happen a exception in `creditAccount` method after `LogUtility.logTxn` method called (here : `// Do somethings`) then `LogUtility.logTxn` method commit or rollback? 
I know `creditAccount` method in this situation rollbacked but I don't know behavior of `logTxn` method.

Comment: you have made your creditAccount() Transactional, hence the operations you do inside the method will also rollback..fo exceptions inside creditAccount ()..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a another connection from data source , means you have a another session with data base, so this connection has its transaction and commit /rollback solitary